# Dark mode changing color and background-color rendering in Xiaomi with MIUI 12.5.8.0 & Android 11

Tags: android, darkmode, xiaomi

I have an app that does not change the `color` & `background-color` of any `<div>` between dark mode and light mode in any phone (iPhones, Samsungs, Pixel, most of Xiaomi,...). But **only** in Xiaomi with MIUI version 12.5.8.0 (stable) and Android 11 does change all colors and background-colors of the app. In this phone, it shows my app as I want only in light mode.

Does anybody know why & how to circumvent it and make no change when switching to dark mode, please? In case this helps, I have tried with the following 2 tags:

a) `<meta name="color-scheme" content="light" />`

b) `<meta name="color-scheme" content="light only" />`

Please, note this is a Cordova app with React.JS code inside, so no native code could be used.

Thanks in advance!